# Как получить массив из контроллера Laravel в JS?

Tags: javascript, laravel

подскажите пожалуйста как получить массив из контроллера Laravel в JS? затем после выбранного варианта в поле устанавливается id региона для отправки формы

Хотел реализовать данный функционал через Javascript component как тут по примеру https://autocomplete.trevoreyre.com/

Но не могу понять как получить данные в JS и добавить выбранный вариант в форму

Имеется вот такой контролер который передает массив в вид

```html
public function index()
    {
        $regions = DB::table('regions')->get();

        return view('region', compact('regions'));
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете axios то можете использовать запрос к другому контроллеру, который будет отдавать только json данные (без view). После создайте необходимый роут. Далее вы можете обращаться к нужному роуту в JS для получения данных.

```
axios.get('/path/to/route')
.then((response) => {
   this.data = response.data;
});
```

перед получением, в контроллере заверните запрос в json_encode
И смотрите в панели инструментов, в разделе "сеть" данные которые вы получаете, если все хорошо то можете их использовать в своем JS.